# lag of multiple column using r

Tags: r, lag

I have a data frame like this

```
    MSFT     AAPL     GOOGL
1 21.11067 4.975767  94.04000
2 20.91273 5.663524  97.50684
3 20.05333 5.681336  90.57909
```

want to create a file with one lag of the previous data like

```
   MSFT     AAPL     GOOGL
1 20.91273 5.663524  97.50684
2 20.05333 5.681336  90.57909
3 20.09447 5.239416  99.60738
```

Trying this code to solve it

```
Lagcolmean <- lapply(names(colmean), function(x){lag(colmean[[x]],k=1)
})
```

But it is not working. Could you help me in this regard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) indexing** `lag` is normally used with time series such as `"ts"`, `"zoo"` and `"xts"` objects.   For a data frame, just remove the first row:

```
DF[-1, ]
```

**2) rollapplyr** If you want to use `rollapply` as in the code in the question then try this:

```
rollapplyr(DF, 2, function(x) x[2])
```

or equivalently:

```
rollapplyr(DF, 2, "[", 2)
```

**3) dplyr** Alternately, the dplyr package does define a `lead` and `lag` which work with data frames:

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% mutate_all(lead)
```